# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline How to block parallel stage until all sub-stages have completed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm running Jenkins Declarative Pipeline controlles by a central Jenkins master and running on 2 slaves on 2 different sites, siteA and siteB.

I have one stage that needs to be run on both sites (ideally in parallel to save time) that waits until some resources are loaded. So this stage basically runs a script that checks if the resources are loaded and if not, waits X seconds and tries again until all resources are loaded.

What happens is that at one site, resource loading is faster than on the other site so when one site finishes the whole stage is done although the other site is not yet complete.

The pipeline for this stage looks like this:

```
stage('myStage') {
            parallel {
                stage('myStage-siteA') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'siteA'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        waitForResourcesLoaded(siteA)
                    }
                }
                stage('myStage-siteB') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'siteB'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        waitForResourcesLoaded(siteB)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to "synchronize" each parallel stage so that the overall stage "myStage" will only be marked complete once each sub-stage has completed?

Comment: What exactly is your "waitForResourcesLoaded" step doing?

Comment: Let's say its calling a URL and parsing the response for a certain keyword. If the keyword is not present it waits 10 seconds and polls again until the keyword is present.

Comment: How do you achieve this? Can you assure that these steps (especially the 10 second wait) are beeing executed in a blocking fashion?

Comment: That is the issue. Both parallel stages run completely independent on 2 different slave nodes and as soon as one slave finishes the whole stage is finished even if the stage on the second slave is not complete.

Comment: Or let's make an even easier example: Create a parallel stage with 2 sub-stages running on 2 different slave nodes. Have one sub-stage wait for 30 seconds and the other wait for 60 seconds. The whole stage will finish after 30 seconds, i.e. when the first slave finishes, and not wait for 60 seconds until the other slave has finished as well.

Comment: I am aware of that. I just wanted to find out if your stages may signal to Jenkins that they are done while they really are just sleeping for 10 seconds.